# Is this conditional probability statement true?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Does it come from Bayes theorem that $P(¬A|B) = 1 - P(A|B)$ ? Because $P(¬A|B) = \frac{P(¬AB)}{P(B)}$ and $P(A|B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$. So $P(¬AB)$ here is equal to $1-P(AB)$ or no?

Comment: You are mixing capital letters and lowercase letters.  If $b$ and $B$ are entirely different events then of course $P(\neg A\mid b)$ doesn't need to equal $1-P(A\mid B)$.  Surely, this isn't what you are wanting to ask about, so be more careful with what you write.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry, i edited it, b and B are the same things

Comment: As to what you intend to ask about., keep in mind the difference between $P((\neg A) \cap B)$ and $P(\neg (A\cap B))$.  Alternatively, using a superscript of $c$ to denote complementation, $P(A^c\cap B)$ is not the same as $P((A\cap B)^c)$.  Here we should rather have $P(A^c\cap B)$ is equal to $P(B) - P(A\cap B)$, seen by [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) or similar, not $1-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Now... finally, $P(A^c\mid B)=\dfrac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(B)}=\dfrac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\dfrac{P(B)}{P(B)}-\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ $ = 1 - \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = 1-P(A\mid B)$, so your identity is true that $P(A^c\mid B) = 1 - P(A\mid B)$ but your attempt at showing it had many algebraic mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf P(\neg A\mid B)$ is a probability mass function.   As such, it definitely follows the Law for Probability of Complements.

$\therefore~~\mathsf P(\neg A\mid B)=1-\mathsf P(A\mid B)$

---

This can be demonstrated using by Bayes' Theorem$^\dagger$, and the Law of Additivity (for Probabilities of Disjoint Unions).   Since $B$ can be partitioned into such events, therefore: $\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(\neg A\cdot B)+\mathsf P(A\cdot B)$.  So:-

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\neg A\mid B)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(\neg A\cdot B)}{\mathsf P(B)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cdot B)}{\mathsf P(B)}\\[2ex]&=1-\mathsf P(A\mid B)\end{align}$$

---

$~\\~$

---

$\dagger$ Rather, that is using the Definition of Conditional Probability, to be fully correct.   $\mathsf P(X\mid Y)\mathop{:=}\mathsf P(X\cdot Y)/\mathsf P(Y)$ when event $Y$ has an non-zero probability measure.